# How to running command npm run in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, rest, npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to do that by watching the video. but I get an error at 09:40 minutes in the video.

Here is the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zkgdLZEdwM&list=LLJ0V5h4uLP4bPK3FNEnKEPw&t=299s&index=1&pbjreload=10)

I am running this command in the terminal; `npm run json:server` and I get the following error.

**My terminal error:**

```
C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\JSONSERVER>npm run json:server

 > jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\JSONSERVER
 > json-server --watch db.json

module.js:540
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'color-convert'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\JSONSERVER\node_modules\ansi-styles\index.js:2:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server: `json-server --watch db.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yavuz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04- 13T21_32_40_798Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```json
  {
    "name": "jsonserver",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Fake REST API for testing",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "json:server": "json-server --watch db.json"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "json-server": "^0.12.1"
    }
  }
```

**db.json**

```json
{
  "users":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "email":"john@gmail.com",
      "age":34,
      "companyId":"1"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "firstName":"Mark",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "email":"mark@gmail.com",
      "age":32,
      "companyId":"2"
    }
  ],
  "companies":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Apple",
      "description":"This is very good firm."     
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Microsoft",
      "description":"This is good firm."    
    }    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the `color-convert` module. Try running `npm install --save color-convert`. This module will be added in your `package.json` as a dependency.